# YouTube deeplinking in video's description

Tags: youtube

So, I've tried to figure this out, but unable to get it to work, nor am I sure it's even possible.

(Related YouTube support page for "[Deeps Links](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=116618)".)

I'm trying to link to a predefined time in the description of a video I loaded; think table of contents. Currently, I'm able to type the section name, hit return, paste the URL in for the video, add `#t=0m10s` to the end of that URL, save the video settings... and then load the video in YouTube, click the link, and have it go to the 10th second in the video.

Problem is I was hoping not to have ugly URLs in the description, or when the URL is clicked have it open the same video to a new window leaving both of the videos playing.

If possible I'd like to link the section name text and have to just it skip to that section of the video without reloading the page or opening the same video on a new page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what worked for me, after signin:

1. Load the video, put a place holder description in.
2. Click your username in the top right corner, then click "Video Manager" is the list below.
3. Find the video you'd like to add deeplinks to within the video's description.
4. Under that video, click "Edit Info"
5. Use the format "Text 00:00" - which is the same as the comments format and only support minutes and seconds, not hours, half-seconds, etc.

Note: It possible this works when loading the video, but already had the video loaded, and on other forums it said that didn't work anyway, so I didn't even bother to test it.

If it matters, the real format I used was "Text (00:00)" - which to me was easy to read and understand, especially after the time becomes hyperlinked and blue.